# Symfony : symfony serve vs apache server dependencies

Tags: php, apache, symfony, server, wamp

I am working on a Symfony project (eshop website). I developed my website with symfony 5.4 and I have been using the command symfony serve to get a live server during the development.

My website is actually working well, but now I need to personalise the url and not using localhost or 127.0.0.1 url by default anymore.

I added the new url I chose in the ".hosts" file in the directory "C:>Windows>System32>drivers>etc" and the server info in the "httpd-vhosts" file in the directory "wamp64>bin>apache>apache2.4.46>conf>extra". Then I used the command "composer require symfony/apache-pack". My website is now working on the new url and I still GET all the data from my Database.

The issue is that I can't Post data in my database anymore using this new url. For example, I can't add a new User, add a product to cart or log a user.
But everytime I run the website with the "symfony serve" command and use the url 127.0.0.1, everything is working well (Add or log user, add product to cart etc.).

Did I miss a dependencies to run it well on the new url ?

Comment: can you show the error that you get on your failing POST requests ?

Comment: First and foremost, the `hosts` file is specific to the device. You need a `DNS` if you want to host it globally through a domain and I strongly recommend you don't do so from your own device. Secondly, are you getting errors? Check your logs if necessary. Finally, what is your `Apache2` configuration?

Comment: For example when I try to add a new user with my register form this error appear when I submit the form "Error The CSRF token is invalid. Please return the form.", but only when I use the personalised url. The form adds the new User in the database only when I use the symfony serve.